# Text column in R - Trying to count the keywords sequentially

Tags: r, string, matching

I am working on a dataset that has a text column. The text has many sentences separated by a semi-colon ';'. I am trying to get a word count in a new column in dataframe for words that match my keyword. However, in one sentence, if there are repeated keywords, they should be considered only once.

For instance -

1. The section 201 solar trade case on cells and modules; Issues relating to section 201 tariffs on imported goods
2. Solar panels, Tawian tariffs, trade
3. Trade issues impacting the solar industry

are the text in one column of the dataframe.
My keywords include solar, solar panels, section 201

I want to count the words in each sentence that match my keywords but if both or all words are there in the sentence, then it is counted only once. Word counts should only consider keywords in different sentences. If one sentence doesn't have a specific keyword, then move towards finding the second keyword.

My output should be -
word_count
2 (as section 201 is mentioned in both sentences, we do not search for solar because the first word in the keyword list matched)
1 (as only solar word is there)
1 (as only solar word is there)

Please suggest a way to resolve this issue. It is a crucial part of my research work. Thanks.

Kind Regards,
Preety

Comment: Is the ordering of your keywords (to be checked one-by-one) supposed to be important? From what you are saying, it seems like the output will be different depending on the order of your keywords.

Comment: Yes, the ordering matters. I am trying to first search for keyword 'Section 201' in all sentences in a row (separated by a semi-colon). If we find the keyword Section 201 in the sentences, we end the search and count the occurrences. If we don't find the first keyword, we move to the second one, and search all the sentences again for the second keyword (here solar). After doing this, I want to create a new column where these counts are added in the dataframe. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: @slowowl - is there anything that could be added to the code such as ifelse, while, something which stops searching keywords when the first keyword is found in the sentences in one row.

Comment: Yes, it can be done using a `while` loop or something, but if the keywords list is not too long, it may not be worthy to do that. For each row, you can look at count for all the keywords and consider the first nonzero number.

Answer (score 0):

I would first split your text column into multiple columns using `tidyr::separate()`; then search for your key phrases within each of these, using `stringr::str_detect()` or base regex functions; then sum across columns using `rowSums(dplyr::across())`. Like so:

```
library(tidyverse)
keywords <- paste("solar", "section 201", sep = "|")
df <- tibble(
  text = c(
    "The section 201 solar trade case on cells and modules; Issues relating to section 201 tariffs on imported goods",
"Solar panels; Tawian tariffs; trade",
"Trade issues impacting the solar industry"
  )
)

df <- df %>%
  separate(text, into = c("text1", "text2", "text3"), sep = ";", fill = "right") %>%
  mutate(
    count = rowSums(
      across(text1:text3, ~ str_detect(str_to_lower(.x), keywords)), 
      na.rm = TRUE
    )
  )
```

The `count` column then contains the results you predicted:

```
df %>%
  select(count)

# A tibble: 3 x 1
#   count
#   <dbl>
# 1     2
# 2     1
# 3     1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think for each number in your example, you want to consider that a separate list item. You want to consider each list item as separate sentences wherever there is semi-colon. Then you want to look for the first occurrence of a keyword in that each list item. That becomes the target keyword for that list item. You then want to count the first occurrence only of that target keyword in each sentence within each list item:

```
  library(dplyr)
  library(stringr)
# I modified your example sentences to include "section 201" twice in sentence 2 in list item #1 to show it will only count once in that sentence
# I modified the order of your keywords, otherwise solar will be detected first in all sentences
  sentences <- list("The section 201 solar trade case on cells and modules; Issues relating to section 201 section 201 tariffs on imported goods", "Solar panels, Tawian tariffs, trade", "Trade issues impacting the solar industry")
  keywords <- c("section 201", "solar", "solar panels")
# Go through by each list item
  lapply(sentences, function(sentence){
# For each list item, sentences, split into separate sentences by ;
# Also I changed each sentence to lowercase, otherwise solar != Solar
    str_split(tolower(sentence), ";") -> split_string
# Apply each keyword and detect if the keyword is in the list_item using str_detect from stringr
    sapply(keywords, function(keyword) str_detect(split_string, keyword)) -> output 
# Output is the keywords that are in each list item
# Choose the first occurrence of a keyword: keywords[output == T][1]
# Detect in each sentence if the keyword is included, then sum the number of occurrences for each list item. Name as the keyword that was detected
      setNames(str_detect(split_string[[1]], keywords[output == T][1]) %>% sum(), keywords[output == T][1])
})
```

Gives a list, with the first occurring keyword identified and the number of first occurrences of that keyword in each sentence within list item:

```
[[1]]
section 201 
          2 

[[2]]
solar 
    1 

[[3]]
solar 
    1
```

Answer (score 0):

If the list of keywords is not too long (say 10 or 20 words), then you can look at the count of all the keywords for each text string. I am adding `;` at the end of each text string so that a sentence always ends with a `;`. The pattern `paste0("[^;]*", key, "[^;]*;")` identifies any sentence containing the word (stored in) `key`.

```
txt <- c("The section 201 solar trade case on cells and modules; Issues relating to section 201 tariffs on imported goods",
         "Solar panels, Tawian tariffs, trade",
         "Trade issues impacting the solar industry")

keys <- c("section 201", "solar panels", "solar")
counts <- sapply(keys, function(key) stringr::str_count(paste0(txt, ";"), regex(paste0("[^;]*", key, "[^;]*;"), ignore_case = T)))
```

Next you can go over each row of `counts` and look at the first non-zero element which should be the value you are looking for.

```
sapply(1:nrow(counts), function(i) {
  a <- counts[i, ]
  a[a != 0][1]
})
```